# Spring Batch - writing in-memory in a step

Tags: spring-batch

I have a Spring batch job which has two steps. The first step's writer writes to memory, that is stores the data in a java data structure.

Is this correct? Does the writer have to write to a persistent storage? If the second step fails, would the job be able to restart correctly if I wrote to the memory in the first step? Is my assumption that a `commit` doesn't mean anything if I do things this way correct?

Answer (score 1):

A writer does not have to write to a persistent storage. However, If the job fails and the JVM is stopped, you will lose that data.

Using a persistent job repository ensures that restart meta-data can survive a JVM crash hence the ability to restart the job where it left off.